# floating button with multiple action

Tags: android, android-studio

how to make floating button with multiple action like this?[Pict Floating Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eulrJ.png)
and can running in API 17 or highest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this library its great and provide a heck lot customization [floating action menu](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)

Answer (score 0):

The library called

> Arc Menu

as in https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu can help you to achieve your requirement.

Even you can resolve your need from same project as

> Ray Menu

..